# How to use the "LIKE" statement in mongodb cakephp

Tags: mongodb, cakephp

I am using ICHIKAWAY's mongodb driver for cakephp.

One thing that I don't really get is how to perform a "LIKE" statement in cakephp using MONGODB.

I tried this statement:

```
$users = $this->User->find('all', array('conditions' => array('data_type' => 'user', 'profile.firstname LIKE' => '%'.$string)));
```

but its not working since "LIKE" is an mysql function.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Google search MongoRegex in the PHP manual

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use MongoRegex

Mongo DB has a LIKE operator - it's simply a regular expression, to use it:

```
$users = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'data_type' => 'user', 
        'profile.firstname' => new MongoRegex("/$string/i")
     )
));
```

### There's an SQL Compatibilty behavior

The Mongodb driver contains a behavior providing [sql syntax compatibility](https://github.com/ichikaway/cakephp-mongodb/blob/cake2.2/Model/Behavior/SqlCompatibleBehavior.php). To use it, simply make sure your model is using this behavior:

```
class User extends AppModel {

    $actsAs = array(
        'MongoDB.SqlCompatible'
    )
}
```

And then you can use your query exactly as it appears in the question:

```
$users = $this->User->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'data_type' => 'user', 
        'profile.firstname LIKE' => '%'.$string
     )
));
```

Comment: How to use "LIKE" with "OR" statement? I am trying to "LIKE" query with two fields.

Comment: @PrashantParekh comments are not for asking questions. _Questions_ are for asking questions.